# How to create application variables in application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm new to using the application.cfc file in our application and some of these don't seem to be working and I can't figure out why. I have tried to cfdump "application". I get Application.DSN, Application.USERNAME, Application.Password, but not Application.SYSTEMPATH or Application.ACCOUNT

```
<cffunction name="onApplicationStart">
  <cfscript>
  Application.availableResources=0;
  Application.DSN = "XXX";
  Application.USERNAME = "XXX" ;
  Application.PASSWORD = "XXX"; 
  Application.SYSTEMPATH = "http://example.com/"; // This doesn't work
  Application.ACCOUNT = XXX; // This doesn't work.  
  Application.counter1=1;
  Application.sessions=0;
  </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: The term, "does not work" is very vague.  What does it mean in this case?

Comment: Also, if you added additional application variables, *after* creating that method, you need to restart the "application" before the new variables will be defined.

Comment: How do I restart onApplicationStart? Do I have to reboot the server?

Comment: Put <cfset onApplicationStart()> as the first line of your onRequestStart function.  Then run any page in that application.  Be sure to comment out the line afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I think this was my problem

Comment: @JackPilowsky Dan's advice doesn't restart the application. It's like suggesting calling an `onClick()` event in JavaScript makes the button on your mouse actually depress. For future reference, if you need to restart your application, call the `applicationStop()` function. The next request will then restart the application properly, from the ground up.

Comment: The way I handle re-initializing the application is by adding something like `if(structKeyExists( url, 'reload'){ onApplicatoinStart()]` in `onRequestStart()`.

Comment: My advice might not restart the application, but it will run the code that sets the variables.

Comment: @DanBracuk I know it's a mostly semantic thing, but if you're going to offer advice to someone, and there's an equally "ideal" and "less than ideal" way of doing things: advise them to do it the ideal way. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: My recommendation matches what I actually do when I want to do something about application variables in development.  It might be less than ideal, but so am I.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

`Application.SYSTEMPATH = GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath());`

This will work too:

`Application.SYSTEMPATH = expandPath( './' );`

Now this...

`Application.ACCOUNT = XXX;` // This doesn't work. (because it is assuming XXX is a variable).

You need this:

`XXX = 'something';` or `XXX = 1;` or Remove it altogether because it serves no purpose.

Then when you call:

`Application.ACCOUNT = XXX;` it won't give you errors.

Or you can just skip it and do this:

`Application.ACCOUNT = 'something';` (a string)
`Application.ACCOUNT = 1;` (a number)

Then it won't fall apart (Because XXX is a variable not a value and you can't call a variable that doesn't exist).

So, if you have a 'variable' it has to have a 'value' (variable/value pair) or at least set a placeholder like `XXX=0;` or `XXX='';` if you must have it.

Have I killed this variable/value dead horse to death??? Lol... :D

Jokes aside let us know if you have another question about your Application variables because some seem unnecessary (can't judge for sure though).

Comment: I put XXX to signigy an integer. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: Ah...well no problem. :)